# One bad sector causes the whole RAID0 to fail?

Tags: hard-drive, mount, hardware-raid, data-recovery

In our server, we have four SSDs. The first one is for OS, and the remaining three are for RAID0.

Today, the disk mount corresponding to RAID0 suddenly goes missing. When I check the disks, the 3rd disk in the RAID0 says there is one bad sector, and it displays `1.0GB` instead of `1.9TB`.

Although the assessment says that `Disk is OK`, but the volumes show `1.0 GB Unknown` instead of `1.9TB Linux RAID Member`.

[image]
[image]

What is going on here? Is our data recoverable?

Comment: There's *zero* redundancy = room for error in RAID*zero*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In RAID0 any problem with any drive means the data is lost.

I want to emphasize the fact there is nothing like "1st part of the file system is first device, 2nd part is on the second and so on". It's like 1st 64kbyte block is the first device, next block on the second, then third, fourth, and the fifth block is again on the first device. So if you remove, for example, the fourth device, what you will get is the hole each fourth 64kbyte block. If you have, say, a JPEG file over 192 kbytes, that file will certainly miss some data. So the recovery will depend on the recovery of data from the dead drive.

You *can try* to recover some data in some cases, but this require the manipulations with the dead drive. Go to the professional recovery service, bring them *all four* drives, pay your bill and pray. No guarantees, however; if they fail, all your data is lost.

Or, just restore everything from backups.

Answer (score 1):

[What are the different widely used RAID levels and when should I consider them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them)

> ## RAID 0
>
> *Good when: Speed at all costs!*
>
> ## Bad when: You care about your data
>
> RAID **0** (aka Striping) is sometimes referred to as *"the amount of data you will have left when a drive fails"*